# Смена ориентации экрана.

Tags: android

Есть активити. В зависимости от ориентации экрана грузятся разные макеты для этой активити. В onConfigurationChange() я говорю, какой макет грузить. Макет загружается отлично, но данные теряются (данные грузятся из интернета в TextView). Я переопределяю TextView в onConfigurationChange(). Что делать дальше? как сделать так, чтобы TextView отображал данные, загруженные в onCreate()?

Comment: [вот ][1] 


  [1]: http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana.html 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поняла. Получается, что каждый TextView ссылается на элемент своего макета. Проблему можно решить, только явно сохраняя значение одного TextView, и передавать это значение другому TextView.